# Disable drag interaction on specific section

Tags: ios, swift, drag-and-drop, uikit, ios11

How i can disable drag interaction on specific sections or cells if 
`tableView.dragInteractionEnabled = true` ?

Now all table cells draggable, but i want to drag specific rows in this table.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can natively allow/disallow moving cells with the `canMoveRowAt` method:

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return yourDataSource[indexPath.row] is YourMovableCellClass
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by returning an empty array in **tableView(_:itemsForBeginning:at:)**

> **Return value** 
> An array of UIDragItem objects representing the contents of the specified row. Return an empty array if you do not want the user to drag the specified row.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdragdelegate/2897492-tableview

In my case (it's a collection view, but approach is the same) I check type of the cell and allow/forbid dragging depending on it:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] {
    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CalendarCollectionCell {
        let item = cell.calendar!
        let itemProvider = NSItemProvider(object: item.name! as NSString)
        let dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: itemProvider)
        dragItem.localObject = item
        return [dragItem]
    } else {
        return [UIDragItem]()
    }
}
```

Comment: In this way, cell is still moving though cell is being placed its original position after moving.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. First, you need to define which cells are draggable.

In your tableView(cellForRowAt...) method set up a conditional check of some sort.

```
// Some code to set up your cell
// All cells are disabled by default
// Only enable the one you want to drag.
cell.userInteractionEnabled = false

// Use this conditional to determine which cells
// become dragable.     
if indexPath.row % 2 = 0 {
    // This is the cell you want to be able to drag.
    cell.userInteractionEnabled = true
}

return cell
```

Comment: This works, but now i can't edit other cells in my table, where i had text fields

Comment: @DenisKartavenko you'll have to manually `userInteractionEnabled = true` on the individual elements that you want to be enabled. Do it AFTER the conditional where you disable them. It's also a good idea to create a validation check to see if it is a draggable cell and run a check when the user touches. I can't remember the method name but it's out there.

Comment: If you disable userInteractionEnabled for specific cells, you can't use other methods like `didSelect` for those specific cells.

Comment: @sagarthecoder that is correct, but he wasn't asking about that.